# Mapbox cant load properly NextJS

Tags: reactjs, debugging, next.js, maps, mapbox-gl-js

I want to implement mapbox (mapbox-gl) using NextJS with React component. The maps appear but there are problems as shown in the following image:

[Maps Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gcc56.png)

Also, if I add a marker with the same latlong as the map, the marker doesn't work properly. if I zoom, the marker will move.

[Markers doesnt work properly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUBsg.png)

Additionally, i cant resize the map.

Here is my code :

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactMapGl, {Marker} from "react-map-gl";

const TOKEN = "TOKEN";

export default function App() {
    const [viewport, setViewport] = useState({
        latitude: 3.597031,
        longitude: 98.678513,
        zoom: 10,
        width: "100vw",
        height: "100vh"
    });
    return (    
                <ReactMapGl
                    mapboxAccessToken={TOKEN}
                    mapStyle="mapbox://styles/mapbox/light-v10"
                    {...viewport}
                    onViewportChange={ viewport => {
                        setViewport(viewport);
                    }}
                />
    )
}
```

I have followed various tutorials and documentation but have not found the answer.
Please help me so that my maps can work properly.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't added any markers or other elements to it. Try adding markers to see if the map is loading correctly. For example:

```
<ReactMapGl
    mapboxAccessToken={TOKEN}
    mapStyle="mapbox://styles/mapbox/light-v10"
    {...viewport}
    onViewportChange={viewport => {
        setViewport(viewport);
    }}
>
    {/* Add markers or other map elements here */}
    <Marker latitude={3.597031} longitude={98.678513}>
        <div>My location / Location icon</div>
    </Marker>
</ReactMapGl>
```

See https://visgl.github.io/react-map-gl/docs/api-reference/marker for reference

Comment: FYI, i already add the marker but i forgot to add it to code snippet above. when i add the marker, the second image is the result. The marker position is not accurate at all and if i zoom the map, the marker will move

Comment: I am guessing your TOKEN is in your env file. If so, add "process.env." in front of it.

Comment: no im not, i write the token on the line above..